# Can't connect to my home Node js server from Internet

Tags: node.js, linux, window

i want to show a "Hello World" in a Node js server. The code is this

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    response.write("Hello");
    response.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8877);
```

My is connected in the next way:

```
Internet <-Hitron modem/router <- Tp-Link router <- Belkin Router <- My PC
```

I have no way to change this.

The server works fine trying in Google Chrome with `localhost:8877` and with my local ip `192.168.2.193:8877`. This last works also in my Android Phone connected to the Belkin Router. But i was all the day trying to open it from the internet (actually putting my ip from sites like myip.com in the navigator and trying to open it from my smartphone using it the mobile data 4g). Searching a bit i try port forwarding in the next way:

[1# router port Forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g56PX.png)

That ip is the ip that is showed in the "Connected Devices Table" of the 1# router corresponding to the 2# router. the 2# router is the same as the first but its ip field corresponds to the ip assigned to the 3# router.[3# router port Forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAxay.png) and the ip field of this last router corresponds to the ip showed in cmd->ipconfig, and it is also showed in the 3# router's device table. Then i use my ip showed in internet sites like whatismyip.com... what is this `190.2.122.xxx`. So, in the browser i put `190.2.122.xxx:8877` but nothing happend.

I try giving that direction to some friends, but they can see nothing (localhost:8877 still works). I try putting `http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8877,"192.168.2.193");`, and changing that ip with "0.0.0.0" and with my external ip "190.2.122.xxx"(with this i have an error starting the server). Then i try changing all the ports numbers, but i cant make it work. As a data, i make a tracert to my public ip 190.2.122.xxx, and i get this

```
Traza a la dirección xxx.122.2.190.ros.express.com.ar [190.2.122.xxx]
sobre un máximo de 30 saltos:

  1    <1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  . [192.168.2.1]
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  3     1 ms    <1 ms     1 ms  hitronhub.home [192.168.0.1]
  4    16 ms    16 ms     8 ms  10.220.0.1
  5    15 ms    16 ms    14 ms  xxx.122.2.190.ros.express.com.ar [190.2.122.xxx]
```

The devices at my home are the 1-2-3, but the tracert to my ip jumps 2 twice more, is this fine? Well, additionaly, i try turning off my Firewall and Antivirus,and activing DMZ in the three routers, i run Windows. I want to make it work, pleeease. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem, it was my ISP. It seems that my ISP manage the clients into  internal networks that cover neighborhoods. So, the ip that i get when i  try whatismyip is the ip assigned to my whole neighborhood. The solution is to contract Public IP for extra money. This is what they explain to me, maybe this will be usefull for someone, i lost a lot of time on this problem.